# More examples of a divergent sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\{|a_n|\}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that the sequence $a_n=(-1)^n$ for all $n\in I_1$ works, since $a_n=(-1)^n$ for all $n\in I_1$ diverges and, since $|a_n|=1$ for all $n\in I_1$ is a constant sequence, it converges;  but I've been trying to think of another example different than that one and I can't find it yet.

Comment: Every example will have the same flavor, but you can certainly have some variation in the sequence. For example, try $a_n=(-1)^n+1/n$ or $a_n=(-1)^n(1+1/n^2)$.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, your second example has the same idea that the one given by @FormulaWriter, and both really helped me!

Comment: You're most welcome. Keep learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_n$ be a positive convergent sequence and $b_n\to \ell\neq 0$.

Let $s_n$ be a sequence taking values in $\{-1,1\}$ which is not eventually constant.

Set $a_n:=s_n b_n$.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to find another way, but after several tries this is crearly the easiest one by far!

Comment: Moreover, this construction characterize the sequences behaving this way, since $b_n=|a_n|$, if we also allow $b_n$ to take the value $0$

Answer (score 0):

**Some examples**

$3 \cos (n \pi)$

$(-2)^n + e^{-n}$

Comment: How would you define the domain of those sequences?

Comment: The domain is $\mathbb N$.